# TinyMCE not working in http request xhr ajax generated page

Tags: ajax, tinymce, textarea, xmlhttprequest

So i I have a page that contains links that call an httpRequest.  The request calls a php file that grabs data from mysql and pre populates a form which is then returned to the browser/webpage.  My problem is that when the page is returned to the browser via the httpRequest/ajax the text area does not display the tinymce editor, it just displays a normal text area. It looks like my request and ajax is working fine the text area just doesn't have the tinycme editor on it.

When i don't use ajax it works fine but when i put it in a separate file and call it via ajax it doesn't bring in the tinymce editor.

Does anyone know how to fix this problem so that my ajax generated page displays the text area with the tinymce editor.  Thank you.

Comment: if httpRequest response is html which you are replacing with old than you have to reinitialize thinyMCE, but rather doing that I would suggest you to use JSON in response and just update value of textarea

Comment: Can you elaborate on this?  I have never used JSON but sounds like you understand my problem.  How would i implement this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed this problem by recalling the function after the ajax call. In this part of my ajax:

```
if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200)
     {
     document.getElementById("Content").innerHTML=xmlhttp.responseText;
     tinymce();
```

Now it works fine.

Answer (score 1):

Lets presume that your thinyMCE instance is initialized with code below

```
// initialize tinyMCE in page
tinyMCE.init({
    mode: "textareas",
    theme: "advanced"
});
```

and you have some kind of button somewhere in the page. For purpose of this tip, i will not give it any ID but you may. Now, using jQuery you can easily attach event handler to that button which will call through AJAX your server and take content which you want to put tinyMCE editor. Code which will do such job would look somehow like below.

```
$(function() {

    $("button").bind("click", function() {
        var ed = tinyMCE.get('content');
        ed.setProgressState(1); // Show progress
        $.getJSON('/page/12.json', { /* your data */
        }, function(data) {
            ed.setProgressState(0); // Hide progress
            ed.setContent(data["body"]);

        }
        });
    });
});
```

You can see that on button.click ajax will call url `/page/12.json` which will return JSON as response.  bare minimum of that response could be:

```
{
   title: "Page title",
   body: "<html><head><title>Page title</title>......</html>"
}
```

I attached anonymous function as callback which will handle response from server. and hide progress indicator which is shown before ajax call.

**About JSON**

JSON is shorten of JavaScript Object Notation. It is JavaScript code!!! So don't be confused about it. Using JSON you can make javascript object which can have attributes you can use later in your code to access particular peace of data which that object "holds". You can look at it as some kind of data structure if it is easier to you.

Anyway, to show you how this JSON can be created by hand look at examples below

```
var data = new Object();
data.title = "Page title";
data.body = "<html....";
```

or

```
var data = {
    title: "page title",
    body: "<html...."
};
```

it is very same thing.

If you want to learn more about JSON point your browser to http://json.org.

**===== alternative =====**

Alternative to json solution could be just plane ajax call to server and response can be plain HTML (from your question I can assume that you have something like this already). So instad of calling `$.getJSON` you can use `$.get(url, callback);` to do same thing. The code at the top of my answer will not dramatically change. Instead of geting JSON in response you will get string which is HTML.

----------- BOTTOM LINE -------

I prefer JSON since it can be easily extended later with other attributes, so there is no painful code changes later ;)

Answer (score 0):

Problem here will be that when you return the full page and render it using the ajax response, your tinymce instance has not been shut down before.
In order to do this you can call this small piece of code before you render the ajax response:

```
tinymce.execCommand('mceRemoveControl',true,'editor_id');
```

In this case the editor should initialize correctly. You are not allowed to initialize a tinymce editor with the same id before shutting the first one down.

Comment: i am a newbie and not sure where i put this bit of code.  I have three files, the wepage, my js script that calls a php page and returns the results back to the webpage.  Which file do i put this code in and where in the file.  Also does this little bit of code go in a script tag?  Thank you.

Comment: you need to place it in the ajax-success function right before the "mceAddControl" call

Answer (score 0):

Strangely i ran into this problem yesterday. Following code should work, but YMMV. Trick is to use the correct steps in [ajax events](http://docs.jquery.com/Ajax_Events). I used the Regular TinyMCE and made use of the jQuery library already included.

Following goes into your tinyMCE initialization `tinyMCE.init()` .  All of the below block should be outside the `document.ready`.

```
 myTinyInit = {
     //.......All essential keys/values ...........

      setup : function(ed) {
                 ed.onChange.add(function( ed ) {
                       tinyMCE.triggerSave();
                }) }
     //.....................

 };
 // Init the tinyMCE 
 tinyMCE.init(myTinyInit);
```

This ensures the content is being saved regularly onto the textarea that holds the value. Next step is setting up the request events.

Normally tinyMCE `mceAddControl` before the ajax post and `mceRemoveControl` after the ajax success should do the trick. But I found that often does not work.

I used the form as the jQuery selector in my case.

```
jQuery( '.myForm' )
.find( 'textarea#myTextArea' )
.ajaxStart(function() {
   // If you need to copy over the values, you can do it here.
   // If you are using jQuery form plugin you can bind to form-pre-serialize event instead.        
   // jQuery( this ).val( tinyMCE.get( jQuery( this ).attr( 'id' )).getContent() );

}).ajaxSend( function() {

    // ! - step 2 
    // My case was multiple editors.
    myEds = tinyMCE.editors;
    for( edd in myEds ) {
       myEds[ eds ].remove();
    } 

    // tinyMCE.get( 'myTextarea' ).remove(); 
    // strangely mceRemoveControl didnt work for me. 
    // tinyMCE.execCommand( 'mceRemoveControl', false, jQuery( this ).attr('id')); 

}).ajaxSuccess(function() {

    // Now we got the form again, Let's put up tinyMCE again.
    txtID = jQuery( this ).attr( 'id' );

    // ! - step 3 
    tinyMCE.execCommand( 'mceAddControl', false, txtID ); 


    // Restore the contents into TinyMCE. 
    tinyMCE.get( txtID ).setContent( jQuery( this ).val());

});
```

**Problems i came across :**

1. Using `mceRemoveControl` always gave me `r is undefined` error persistently.
2. If you get a blank tinyMCE editor, check the DOM whether the ID of the textarea is replaced with something like `mce_02`, this means that TinyMCE is being initialized again or something is wrong with the order. If so, the tinyMCE is duplicated with each save.
3. if you are new to JS, I recommend using jQuery with the [form](http://jquery.malsup.com/form/) plugin, it might be easier for you. But do use the regular non-jquery tinyMCE, as it is well documented.